# output UTF-8 text files in excel vba

Tags: vba

I want to output the Japanese written on the sheet as a UTF-8 text file. The current code also works, but this code export SJIS file.
Is the problem that I am getting it in range and outputting it?
Or is there something wrong with the SaveAs Filename code?

```
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
rng.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

Rows(1).Delete

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fPath & fName, FileFormat:=xlText, Local:=True
ActiveWindow.Close

Worksheets("sheetname").Select
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Please, try `FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText`...

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried it, but the result was a UTF-16 file with BOM.

Comment: do you know any other possible ways?

Comment: Then, try `xlCSVUTF8`. Letting the ."txt" format in the file name...

Comment: Since you do not say anything, I can understand that the above suggestion didn't work too. Is the separator of the text file a space (" "), `Comma`, `Tab`, or what? I will try helping with a different approach.

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried xlCSVUTF8, it was UTF-8 with BOM . but I need the separator of the text tab...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will not use Excel `SaveAs. It will build a string from the existing cells and save it in a different way:

```
Sub testExportUth8_NoBOM()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, strTxt As String, strLine As String
    Dim strName As String, arr, i As Long, j As Long, sep As String
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    arr = sh.UsedRange.Value
    sep = "," 'you can use here any needed separator
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            strLine = strLine & arr(i, j) & sep
        Next j
        strLine = left(strLine, Len(strLine) - 1)
        strTxt = strTxt & strLine & vbCrLf
        strLine = ""
    Next i
    strName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\testUTF8_No_BOOM.txt" 'use here the name you want
    WriteUTF8WithoutBOM strTxt, strName
End Sub

Private Function WriteUTF8WithoutBOM(strText As String, fileName As String)
  Dim UTFStream As Object, BinaryStream As Object
  With CreateObject("adodb.stream")
     .Type = 2: .Mode = 3: .Charset = "UTF-8"
     .LineSeparator = -1
     .Open: .WriteText strText, 1
     .Position = 3 'skip BOM' !!!
     Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
         BinaryStream.Type = 1
         BinaryStream.Mode = 3
         BinaryStream.Open
        .CopyTo BinaryStream
        .Flush
    .Close
  End With
    BinaryStream.SaveToFile fileName, 2
    BinaryStream.Flush
    BinaryStream.Close
End Function
```

Please run it and send some feedback.

Comment: I tried the code, but I couldn't get it to work because the / and \ marks were mixed up in the filename path... So I tried "/testUTF8_No_BOOM.txt" instead of "\testUTF8_No_BOOM.txt", but it didn't work.

Comment: Why should you change the path separator? Isn't Windows your OS? Isn't the working workbook situated on a local path? Did you try using the path from your initial code?

Comment: This is a windows os. I'm trying this on a computer at work. The only local drive is c, so when I tried to output to that, I got a 3004 error. So I changed the path and tried to implement it, but I got a 3004 error as well.

Comment: Try using the file name you used in the previous trials, please. The full name...

Comment: @SJ W Glad I (finally) could help! But, just from curiosity: why did you talk about mixing up the slashes with back slashes? Did you try the code as it is and it raised an error? If yes, on which code line? Please, also try inserting `Debug.Print strName `, immediately after giving it a value. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: When I run the code you gave me, I got an error. The reason is that when I use "ThisWorkbook.Path" to get it, it becomes https. https://myoffice.companyname. ~~/~~~/~~~.txt and cannot be written.
So I changed it to local drive C and it worked correctly.

Comment: In the url, it is / instead of \, so the code above was mixed up.

Comment: I asked you: "Isn't the working workbook situated on a local path", but your answer ("The only local drive is c, so when I tried to output to that, I got a 3004 error") made me think that the path should be on the local computer. Anyhow, if the workbook is on OneDrive, or different cloud location, you need a URL path type.

Comment: I had answered that I thought the desktop location was on the C drive, but when I debugged it later, it was on the onedrive.

Comment: So I set the path to drive C and it worked.
I also tried to change the onedrive path to a non-URL path, and that fixed the problem.

Comment: @SJ W I missed the part of HTTPS path type, the part after 'https' has been transformed in a link and I usually do not follow links not knowing what to expect from them... Now, replacing backslash with slash should work. Since it did not, I think it is only a matter of permissions (to programmatically write on OneDrive). This is a different issue and needing the file on the local computer, it is good that you could solve the problem. Case closed! Have a nice day!